# c# attributes and generic--list

Tags: c#, attributes, generic-list

I have such generic class of list:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Lab7
{
    public class MyListClass<T>: IEnumerable<T>
    {
        public delegate void MyDelegate();
        public event MyDelegate AddEvent;
        public event MyDelegate RemEvent;   

        List<T> list;

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get { return list[index]; }
            set { list[index] = value; }
        }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            list.Add(item);
            if (AddEvent != null)
                AddEvent();   
        }

        public void Remove(T item)
        {
            list.Remove(item);
            if (RemEvent != null)
                RemEvent();   
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            list.RemoveAt(index);
            if (RemEvent != null)
                RemEvent();   
        }

        public MyListClass()
        {
            list = new List<T>();
        }

        public MyListClass(List<T> list)
        {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return list.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return list.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #region Events
        /*static void AddHandler()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Объект добавлен в коллекцию"); 
        }
        static void RemoveHandler()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Объект удалён из коллекции коллекцию");
        }*/
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Where i must put attribute to write something to different classes, according to type of this list? How do I write this attribute?

I didn't understand sense of attributes in this lab.

If you want to see all lab, it's here

> Write generic class of list with
>   opportunity to generate events when
>   you call some class methods.
>   Information about events must e
>   written in some files, which must be
>   determinated by attached to this class
>   attribute.

Comment: genrelic-class of list, and attribute ... I didn't understand, because our teacher don't say which attribute I must write, I think, that's will good to write attribute to my xmlclass(which write's data to xml file) which depends of type of generic list, if generic object type is int, i write to one file, if double, i write to another file. But I don't know how to do this by attribute. Can you give me ideas, and help me?

Comment: don't understand what you say. How could attribute help with different object types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asked to write to a specified file information about the events fired when some specified methods are called. This file must be specified through a `class` level `Attribute`.

I think (not easy to understand what you are asking) the `Attribute` should be defined in the generic type `T`.

If thats what you are asking I would do something similar to the following:

1. Define your custom attribute:

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)] 
   public class LogFileAttribute: Attribute
   {
       readonly string path;

       public LogFileAttribute(string path)
       {
           this.path = path;
       }

       public string Path { get { return this.path; } }
   }
   ```
2. Modify your generic list class:

   ```
   public class MyListClass<T> : IEnumerable<T>
   {
        public delegate void MyDelegate();
        public event MyDelegate AddEvent;
        public event MyDelegate RemEvent;
        private LogFileAttribute logFileAttribute;

        List<T> list;

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get { return list[index]; }
            set { list[index] = value; }
        }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            list.Add(item);
            if (AddEvent != null)
            {
                 AddEvent();
            }
            if (this.logFileAttribute != null)
            {
                logEvent("Add");
            }
        }

        public void Remove(T item)
        {
            list.Remove(item);
            if (RemEvent != null)
            {
                RemEvent();
            }
            if (this.logFileAttribute != null)
            {
                logEvent("Remove");
            }
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            list.RemoveAt(index);
            if (RemEvent != null)
            {
                RemEvent();
           }
           if (this.logFileAttribute != null)
           {
               logEvent("RemoveAt");
           }
        }

        public MyListClass()
        {
            list = new List<T>();
            checkLogFileAttribute();
        }

        public MyListClass(List<T> list)
        {
            this.list = list;
            checkLogFileAttribute();
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return list.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return list.GetEnumerator();
        }

        private void logEvent(string methodName)
        {
            File.AppendAllLines(this.logFileAttribute.Path, new string[] { methodName + " called." });
        }

        private void checkLogFileAttribute()
        {
            object[] attributes = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(LogFileAttribute), false);
            if (attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                this.logFileAttribute = (LogFileAttribute)attributes[0];
            }
        }

    }
   ```

Now if you define the following class:

```
[LogFile(@"C:\EventLog.txt")]
public class Foo
{
    readonly int id;
    public Foo(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get { return this.id; } }
}
```

And run the following code:

```
MyListClass<Foo> foos = new MyListClass<Foo>();
foos.Add(new Foo(1));
foos.Add(new Foo(2));
```

you will get the desired behavior (if I understood your question correctly).

**EDIT:** Removed `Append` form `LogFileAttribute` as it didn't make any sense in this context.

Comment: File.AppendAllLines(this.logFileAttribute.Path, new string[] { methodName + " called." });

Comment: Append means that you do not overwrite the file, you append new lines to the end of the existing file.

Answer (score 1):

if i've decoded your question correctly u need something like this:

```
[
YouFileDeterminant(@"c:\first.log"),
YouFileDeterminant(@"d:\second.log")
]
public class MyListClass<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
...
}
```

then before firing the event u should get those attribute(s) to determine files

Comment: yes, pretty like that. But how I can use this attribute in class? can you give me some link where I can read in simple form of using attributes?